# Transfer data from XML response to SoapUI property

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui, open-source

I am very new to SoapUI (open source version) and REST. We have an ERP system that uses REST via web services to allow third part applications to communicate with it. I am using SoapUI to test out how these calls work. I use a user name & password to get a token for my session. I've used the Property Transfer inside SoapUI to set the user name & password.  The result is in XML:

```
<MGRestTokenResponse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Message>success</Message>
   <Token>--I WANT THIS DATA--</Token>
</MGRestTokenResponse>
```

When I used the Property Transfer to get the token, the best I could get is to store the entire XML output. After a lot of Googling, the only solution I could come up with is in a follow up step, use the following Groovy code:

```
def content = context.expand('${Set Test Properties#sectoken}')
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(content)
def token = xml.getAt("Token")
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Set Test Properties").setPropertyValue("sectoken",token.toString())
```

Is this the correct/preferred way to extract data from an XML response in SoapUI? Should I have done anything with the text field below the "Target" settings? I assume that the process would be similar with JSON (swapping the Slurper our for Json).

I've got a lot of testing I need to use SoapUI from & I want to be sure I'm using the tool properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you found it right, There are 2 ways of fetching data.

1. Property Transfer
2. Groovy script

a) XmlParser/XmlSlurper
b) xmlHolder

Also please note that if your xml has **namespaces**, then only **xmlHolder** can help you.

```
i.e. <f:table>
<f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
<f:width>80</f:width>
<f:length>120</f:length>
<f:table>
```

i.e. //*:length will still remain valid, but if you use xml.getAt(length) this may not work

`def groovyUtils= new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def xml=groovyUtils.getXmlHolder('YourRestRequestName#Request')
def token=xml.getNodeValue("//*:Token")
log.info token`

and the correct syntax for fetching value via Property transfer step is

```
 declare namespace ns1='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/'; 
 //ns1:MGRestTokenResponse[1]/ns1:Token[1]
```

[image]

Using groovy is more benefical as it makes your task very easy if you want so many validation.

- a) what if you want to validate the length of token
- b) Value is alphanumeric and there are 5 subnodes inside
  MGRestTokenResponse So from long term perspective and detailed
  validation relying on Groovy is a better option

Comment: I just tested your answer and I had to change one thing. I set the Property to Response instead of Request & it worked perfectly.  Your answer also gave me a better understanding of navigating the XML. I've just purchased a course on SoapUI to get better at it but this worked out great. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This should be possible with the property transfer test step. The reason I bring this up is that I find that is it less taxing on the system memory than groovy scripts.

The below should be able to transfer the property you are looking for provided you have added a properties test step.

[image]

Please let me know if this helps

Comment: I've just tried it & it isn't working. My 'Token' property remains null & the following tests fail as a result. I've tried both Response and ResponeAsXml but neither seems to store the token using the steps you've outlined. I am using SoapUI 5.4.0 open source if that makes any difference.

I agree with you that doing it in the Property Transfer step is much cleaner, which is what I wanted, rather than have a step to store the entire output then parse the text with Groovy to store just the token.